# Image is not loading in website

Tags: php, html, image

I am having trouble showing an image on a webpage. The URL to the image is correct, yet it doesn't show the image, but rather the alternative text.

This is the IMG code:

```
<img scr="../../images/badges/<?php echo $blog_post['content']; ?>" alt="" />
```

The html output is this:

```
<img scr="../../images/badges/acht.png" alt="received-badge" />
```

I double checked the URL to the image, but that is correct.
The code is also not wrong and the PHP variable is always filled with a default value. These images do exist.

I know it should work, because there are more file I include with PHP using the "../../" structure in the URL.

I really feel stupid to not get it to work.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, that I checked FireBug in FireFox and in the "Net" tab it should show all the images that should be loaded and there is nothing there.

Anyone got an idea?

Thanks in Advance,
Mark Dijkema

Comment: i think you should accept answer because your question is still appearing in unanswered.

Comment: Yes, I just did. I had to wait a few minutes, before I could flag an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<img scr...` should be `<img src...`.

Comment: good luck, I spotted ^HIS^ typo first but you got accepted answer, anyways congratz

Answer (score 10):

Change `scr` to `src`, you have typo :)

Comment: You sir, are my hero. I am developing websites for 2 years now and I never made this mistake. I feel so stupid. Thank you so much

Comment: This is where legacy HTML infuriates me. Because src isn't a real word, it's difficult for your "in-head" parser to spot that problem. "source" spelled wrongly would have jumped out of the page at you.

Comment: Yeah, to bad there are no real HTML editors who spot the problem. I am using the Netbeans IDE, but he doesn't recognize the problem. :|

Comment: Alright, i'll give them a try soon. Thanks